# How to estimate a double integral with small upper bound via Landau notation $O(t^3)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

In the paper I am reading, it is claimed that
\begin{align*}
\vartheta_0\int_0^tf_s \int_0^s a_ry_r(\vartheta_0)drds = \vartheta_0 f_0 a_0 y_0 \frac{t^2}{2} + O(t^3)
\end{align*}
for a small upper bound $t.$ We have $t,s \in [0,T]$, $f$ and $a$ are positive and bounded functions and we have the relation
\begin{align*}
y_r(\vartheta_0)=y_0+\vartheta_0\int_0^ta_sy_s(\vartheta_0)ds.
\end{align*}
Why is this Landau notation true? I could of course estimate the integral on the LHS via $\leq t^2 \cdot \max_{s\in [0,t]} f_s \max_{s\in [0,t]} a_s \max_{s\in [0,t]}y_s$, but I do not see how the factor $O(t^3)$ comes into play. Intuitively, the idea is clear: one uses the start values $f_0, a_0, y_0$ instead of the correct ones on the interval $[0,t]$ and therefore, one generates an error. But why is this error in $O(t^3)$? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What are the regularities of your functions ? What does $y_r(\vartheta_0)$ means ? Has $y$ two variables ? Please add more context

Comment: @Cactus: Done so, thanks for your comment. I assume that all functions are "nice" and it's just about the idea of how to estimate an integral with small upper bound by using the values at time 0.